# Regular expression split in python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Could you please let me know how does we split a string with multiple delimiters in python and one of the delimited is a text

for example,
we have a string 'this is my worksplace.Work restricted.this is a sample text.this is text 2.Work restricted'

I want a split using dot first and then with 'Work restricted'

I did a regular expression using dot and able to get the list, sample below

```
textforsplit='this is my worksplace.Work restricted.this is a sample text.this is text 2.Work restricted'
testArray=re.split('[.]',textforsplit)
```

this is  working with dot and I am able to get the list as

```
['this is my worksplace','Work restricted','this is a sample text','this is text2', 'Work restricted']
```

But I want to filter the results again and need to get a list excluding the 'Work restricted' text, that is the final list should be

```
['this is my worksplace','this is a sample text, 'this is text 2']
```

is there anyway I can achieve this using modifications in the regular expression conditions in python

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use a regular expression for this, since the delimiter is a fixed string. Just use the regular `str.split()` method. Then you can remove `Work restricted` using a list comprehension.

```
textforsplit='this is my worksplace.Work restricted.this is a sample text'
testArray=textforsplit.split('.')
testArray = [x for x in testArray if x != 'Work restricted']
```

Comment: thank you for your response, I updated the question to avoid confusion,  first we have to split with dot and then with 'Word restricted'. Could you please help

Comment: thanks much, this works, I will test all the conditions and update

Comment: Can we add multiple conditions in the if statement, one scenario is the string can be like 'this is a simple text.Work restricted.' there can be a dot at the end and the split will create a empty list element ''. here, ['this is a simple text','Work restricted','']. So, I need to remove the empty elements ''. So, in the if condition I can check for the != 'Work restricted or '', correct?

Comment: `if x != 'Work restricted' and x != '' and ...`

Comment: or `if x not in {'Work restricted', '', ...}`

Answer (score 1):

You can filter them with a list comprehension:

```
testArray = [x for x in testArray if x != 'Work restricted']
```

Comment: thank you for your response, I updated the question to avoid confusion,  first we have to split with dot and then with 'Word restricted'. Could you please help

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure regex solution using `findall`:

```
>>> textforsplit='this is my worksplace.Work restricted.this is a sample text.this is text 2.Work restricted'
>>> print ( re.findall(r'(?:^|(?<=\.))(?!Work restricted)[^.]+', textforsplit) )
['this is my worksplace', 'this is a sample text', 'this is text 2']
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NwRwrd/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:^|(?<=\.))`: If we are start or previous character is a dot
- `(?!Work restricted)`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have `Work restricted` ahead of us
- `[^.]+`: Match 1+ of any character that is not DOT